File Event is Sometimes Empty
I'm trying to write a simple app that lets someone upload and view audio files. I have a piece below that takes the file and sends it. It works like 50% of the time. The other 50% of the time event.target.files is null and  so I end up sending a blank form. I'm not sure why. Any help is much appreciated.
function FileUploadButton() {  
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState([]);  
  
  const handleFileSelect = (event) => {  
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(selectedFile);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Audio", selectedFile)  
    
    fetch(url+'/upload',{ method: 'POST', 
     body: formData
    }).then((res1) => {
      if (!res1.ok) {
      res1.json().then((data) => {console.log(data)});
    }
  })
  }  
  
  return (  
    <div>  
      <input type="file" name="Audio" onChange={handleFileSelect} />  
    </div>  
  );  
}  


Event if you updated state, the value in seletecedFile will still be the old value in the current execution. The logic to perform the request should handle by a useEffect hook where it runs when the state changes.

That's because the setter that useEffect returns is sort of asynchronous function (its effect is not immediate - it schedules state change for later when React's rendering phase ends). This means that value of selectedFile doesn't change in the current call.
The react documentation mentions this on the useState page in the Caveats section.

The set function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

If you want to use the file in the event handler, use event.target.files[0] directly (you can assign it in a local variable too, those still work normally). Just be aware that it can still be empty, so you should check it anyway before submitting the form.
Additionally, you don't necessarily even need the useState for your example, you can submit it directly.

Hello, Thank you. I'm a beginner, but in React, as I understand it (which may be wrong), the render doesn't happen until the state changes, correct? There are other components/functions that rely on that state change. So I should check to see if the user clicked the button to submit, and not whether or not the file was actually sent?

Is there a way I can wait until the set function actually reads the set variable?

It's not necessary to wait for a button submit. That really depends how is your app designed to work. Sometimes it's desirable to upload file immediately.

Once you call setState, the component should update eventually and then it will re-render. Just make sure to always replace the state value. See: https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state.

As for how you can have a separate submit action, try this. Have state for the file, as you have right now, and only set state in the handle FileSelect. Next add a button, make it disabled when selectedFile is null and add a handler to button's onClick event that sends the request. As a bonus, you can try to figure out how to prevent double submit when upload takes to long (e.g. adding visual feedback of ongoing upload and disabling the button during upload).
